# how to put language resources in a separate project to generate satellite assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, satellite-assembly

I've been using http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30035/Simple-WPF-Localization project to localize an app because (well) it's simple and straight-forward and supports dynamic language change.

I put all the language resources in the main project (i.e. resources.resx, resources.ja-JP.resx). That way the satellite assemblies get generated automatically and into the correct folder structure.

However, i would like to put all the language resources (except the default/neutral one - resources.resx) in a separate project. With that, i don't need to rebuild the main project (which has the application source) if i only needed to change something in one of the translations.

So, i would like to know if there is a standard way (or at least a very straight-forward way) of creating a VS project that only contains language resources.

I already tried creating an empty project and setting the output to class-library and the assembly to match my executable's name. It does create the correct satellite assemblies in the correct folder but it also generates a dll. It would be real simple if there's a project-type for c# or wpf that are completely language resource-only but i can't seem to find any references about it.

(btw, i'm using VS 2010 with WPF project)

thanks for any help!

Comment: There's a c#/wpf project here https://tcimultilanguage.codeplex.com/ which has a resource-only assembly that contains multi-language support.  It's VS 2013 though, you may have a spot of bother with it in VS 2010

Comment: actually wanted to stick with the default way of how it's done in 2010. so, i ended up just adding a script in the build events to clear out the unnecessary dll output but thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

(late reply, but for the community)

Depending on exactly what one want to achieve, building satellite assemblies from the command line might be the ticket for you (using command line tools resgen and al.exe).

I had to do this to enable non developers to modify resources, and without going through the development team/build/deploy cycle, have their changes take effect and allow them to validate.

This is mentioned in a lot of places in the MSDN docs, but I haven't seen many end-to-end samples demostrating it:

https://github.com/JohanPGunnarsson/LocalizedResx